# What does "per account per region" mean in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have seen the term, "per account per region" at many places in AWS documentation e.g. at https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

> No. AWS Lambda is designed to run many instances of your functions in parallel. However, AWS Lambda has a default safety throttle for the number of concurrent executions ***per account per region*** (visit here for info on default safety throttle limits). You can also control the maximum concurrent executions for individual AWS Lambda functions, which you can use to reserve a subset of your account concurrency limit for critical functions, or cap traffic rates to downstream resources.

What does it mean?

My understanding is that it is the sum of accounts per region e.g. Let's say your org has three accounts in two regions and two accounts in one region, the total will be 3x2 + 2x1 = 8

Is it the correct understanding?

Comment: Do you have specific example where it is unclear to you what "per account per region" refers to?

Comment: Each account and each region has a separate limit, your Account A in eu-west-1 has the limit, your Account A in us-east-1 has a limit, your Account B in eu-west-1 has another limit. Their usages do not interact and are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It effectively means that the limits are enforced **in each region separately**.

It is also enforced at the **Account level**, so limits in *your* account don't impact limits in *my* account. Same if you control multiple accounts.